# remove html tags from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string that contain some html tags. I have to remove these tags.

```
 var str = "<msup> <mi class=\"fm-mi-length-1\" mathvariant=\"italic\">x</mi><span class=\"fm-script fm-inline\" style=\"vertical-align: 1.33em;\"><span mtagname=\"mfrac\" style=\"vertical-align: 0em;\"><span class=\"fm-vert fm-frac\"><table><tbody><tr><td class=\"fm-num-frac fm-inline\"><mn>3</mn></td></tr><tr><td>/<mn>4</mn></td></tr></tbody></table></span></span></span></msup><mo class=\"fm-infix\">+</mo><msup><mi class=\"fm-mi-length-1\" mathvariant=\"italic\">y</mi><span class=\"fm-script fm-inline\" style=\"vertical-align: 1.33em;\"><span mtagname=\"mfrac\" style=\"vertical-align: 0em;\"><span class=\"fm-vert fm-frac\"><table><tbody><tr><td class=\"fm-num-frac fm-inline\"><mn>2</mn></td></tr><tr><td>/<mn>3</mn></td></tr></tbody></table></span></span></span></msup>";
```

This is my string. I have to remove the table ,tr, td tags. for this i did

```
 var fmt = $(str).find('table, tbody, tr, td').contents().unwrap().end().end();
            eqn = fmt.html();
```

But the result contains the first tables contents only. The second tables contents are not coming in result. What is wrong in my code.

please check the fiddle given.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t1wtaojz/2/)

Please help..Thanks..

Comment: Try use .text() method like this fmt.text();

Comment: Use Google before posting your question on stack-overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
eqn = fmt.html()
```

just use this:

```
eqn = $('<div>').append(fmt).html();
```

Here is an example for you http://jsfiddle.net/t1wtaojz/3/

Comment: It is because jQuery html() method will return content only for first element in array. So, to show all 3 elements you have to append them into the new one and then show the html content of it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that :

```
$(str).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You catch the bull a min before.... use Alexander 1fmt.text(); or $(str).text();